# EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_i386_BPT, subcode=0x0)

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I was trying to insert to CoreData after retrieving from API. But when I tried it, It show as `EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_i386_BPT, subcode=0x0)`. In Log, it's only show as `(lldb)`. I don't think it's not related with outlet coz I didn't set any special outlet aside from default ones during my writing. I also tried to solve other one solutions but none of it work on me. Please help a way to solve it.

**Screenshot**

[image]

**Code**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()

           var appDel :AppDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
           var context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.managedObjectContext!

           let urlString = "https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1/sites/mmotaku.net/posts/"
           let url = NSURL(string: urlString)

           let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

           let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
               if (error != nil) {
                   println(error)
               } else {
                   let jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as NSDictionary

                   let posts = jsonResult["posts"] as NSArray
                   var newBlogItem:NSManagedObjectContext

                   var items = [[String:String]()]
                   var item = [String:String]()


                   for var i = 0; i < posts.count; i++ {

                  newBlogItem = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("BlogItem", inManagedObjectContext: context) as NSManagedObjectContext

                       var authorDict = posts[i]["author"] as NSDictionary
                       newBlogItem.setValue(authorDict["name"], forKey: "name")
                       newBlogItem.setValue(posts[i]["title"], forKey:"title")
                       newBlogItem.setValue(posts[i]["content"], forKey: "content")
                       newBlogItem.setValue(posts[i]["date"], forKey: "date")

                       context.save(nil)   
                       println("completed")

                   }
               }
           })

           task.resume()


           if let split = self.splitViewController {
               let controllers = split.viewControllers
               self.detailViewController = controllers[controllers.count-1].topViewController as? DetailViewController
           }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to cast to the wrong type.  The result of the insert will be an `NSManagedObject` (or your subclass of NSManagedObject), not `NSManagedObjectContext`.  So, if your subclass is `BlogItem` change the insert as follows:

```
newBlogItem = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("BlogItem", inManagedObjectContext: context) as BlogItem
```

If you haven't subclassed, just use `NSManagedObject` at the end of the line, in place of `BlogItem`.

Comment: it works, I wrongly cast as NSManagedObjectContext instead of NSManagedObject